# Is it safe to slightly unscrew a light bulb so it doesn't complete the circuit?

Tags: lighting, socket

It's dangerous to leave an open socket, but I have a light fixture that's too bright and I don't have a dead bulb to put in one of the sockets. Is it safe to put a bulb in but unscrewed enough that it does not light up? That seems like it could be more dangerous than leaving it open entirely.

Comment: Is the lamp socket in reach, or in a ceiling fixture?

Comment: "It's dangerous to leave an open socket"  Only if someone can reach it easily.

Comment: Why not just buy weaker low wattage bulbs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Electrically safe; mechanically unsafe

Electrically, the partially screwed in light bulb forms a near-perfect insulator (an air gap) between the center electrode of the lightbulb and the center pin of the lightbulb socket. The problem is that the threads of the light bulb socket are gently tapered and made from a malleable sheet metal. The bulb is only secure from working its way completely back out (and falling from the lightbulb socket mount) when fully threaded in -- placing the threads under compression. People walking in the room, vehicle traffic outside/nearby, and other daily life vibration sources can (eventually) fully unseat the bulb causing it to fall.

### Capping a lightbulb socket

Others here have suggested various "capping" strategies. Capping is the process of securing an electrical outlet from unintended use. For example, placing a thin insulator (like paper) between the threads of the bulb and the socket allows you to fully seat the light bulb without making an electrical connection (be careful with paper though, some paper coatings are mildly conductive -- fire risk -- and paper absorbs moisture). You might also consider a socket outlet adapter as a cap:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As long as nobody is either young enough or stupid enough to put their fingers in it, it's safe.
I once told someone who was totally ignorant of how electricity works that they should turn off the wall sockets when not in use to prevent electrons leaking out and poisoning anyone in the room :-)

OTOH, when I was a child I poked a wire into a wall socket and shorted it it with a big bang. Make sure this cannot happen.

Comment: The latter can also be done intentionally (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, Edison did not think about safety issues when he invented his lamp socket:-)

Of course, it is dangerous to leave a lamp socket open. If you are not going to use the lamp, insert some insulation (a piece of paper works) and screw it up. In the 60s, "bad boys" at my school used to wet the paper with water and that is how the lamp initially lit up. But then the water would evaporate and the lamp would go out... and that was the reason they let us out of school:-)

Other "bad guys" made plugs with internally shorted leads and plugged them into the sockets. It was getting short, the fuses were burning... and they let us out of school again:-)